# No bake vs instant pudding

Tags: pudding

Recipe calls for regular pudding mix with other ingredients. Not making into pudding. I can only find instant pudding. What should I do

Comment: Can you help us understand what you are planning to do? Include the recipe or a link? Regular pudding mix (for cooking) is mostly starch and flavor components, sometimes sugar.

Comment: Instant pudding uses modified corn starch (which is pre-gelatanized so it doesn't require boiling to activate) and phosphates (which cause milk proteins to gel up) so it can do it's thing with cold milk. regular pudding might contain modified corn starch but it mostly powered by regular corn starch so it requires boiling.